# How to return number of matches according to specific term in search query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my search query I have this:

```
...
term: { CategoryId: [1,2,3] }
...
```

I need to return how many matches were found for each category. For now just `total` number of matches is returned. Is it possible? I think this might be related to `aggregation`, however I can't find the right solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample query can be,

```
POST /test/products/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "category": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "category"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

so response is as,

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "category": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "1",
               "doc_count": 10
            },
            {
               "key": "2",
               "doc_count": 12
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Which gives no of documents for each category. 
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hmm, and is it possible to also return some more data along with `CategoryId`? I need for example `CategoryName` for each aggregation to display filters for user... Otherwise I would have to retrieve categories names from DB after elastic returned category ids...

Comment: I posted it as separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960348/how-to-retrieve-more-data-in-aggregation