# How to retrieve more data in aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using following aggregation:

```
searchOptions.aggs = {
  categories: {
    terms: {
      field: "CategoryId"
    }
  }
}
```

This works however I only get `key: 1, docs_count: X` aggregations which is useless - I have to get also `CategoryName` along with `CategoryId`...

Comment: So, Do you want to get categoryName for that Id or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get category name for that id then,

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "category": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "categoryId"
         },
         "aggs":{
             "categoryName" :{
                 "terms" :{
                     "field" :"categoryName"
                 }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So, sub-aggregation(which is nested in above) gives you categoryName for its id.

Comment: Always Glad, As I can help. :)